# Change values of select box of "show 10 entries" of jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

By default, jquery datatable shows 10 by default and has

options  : **10,25,50,100**

How can I change these options?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Don't forget to change the iDisplayLength as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tbl_id').dataTable({
        "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 25
    });
} );
```

Comment: ```iDisplayLength``` is now legacy. Use ```pageLength``` instead.

Comment: You can also use the option name: `lengthMenu` instead of `aLengthMenu ` in newer versions too.

Answer (score 46):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, "All"]],
    "pageLength": 25
    } );
} );
```

aLengthMenu :
   This parameter allows you to readily specify the entries in the length drop down menu that DataTables shows when pagination is enabled. It can be either a 1D array of options which will be used for both the displayed option and the value, or a 2D array which will use the array in the first position as the value, and the array in the second position as the displayed options (useful for language strings such as 'All').

**Update**

Since DataTables v1.10, the options you are looking for are `pageLength` and `lengthMenu`

Comment: i have used your above logic, its working fine, but in the show entries select box, still i am having 10 25 50, in my case it should display 5 10 50 100.. How to change the select box entries?

Answer (score 10):

In my case , **aLengthMenu** is not working. So i used this. And it is working.

```
jQuery('#dyntable3').dataTable({            
            oLanguage: {sLengthMenu: "<select>"+
            "<option value='100'>100</option>"+
            "<option value='200'>200</option>"+
            "<option value='300'>300</option>"+
            "<option value='-1'>All</option>"+
            "</select>"},
            "iDisplayLength": 100

        });
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much for this update. aLengthMenu  was not working for me either.

Answer (score 8):

According to [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html) the proper way to do this is adding the lengthMenu property with an array of values.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: I like that you added the link to the source. This worked perfectly

Answer (score 5):

```
 $('#tblSub1View').dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "aoColumnDefs": [{
                        'bSortable': false,
                        'aTargets': [0, 1]
                    }],
                    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

if you click some button，then change the datatables the displaylenght，you can try this ：

```
 $('.something').click( function () {
var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
oSettings._iDisplayLength = 50;
oTable.fnDraw();
});

oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this easily without writing Js.
Just add an attribute called data-page-length={put your number here}.
see example below, I used 100 for example

```
<table id="datatable-keytable" data-page-length='100' class="p-table table table-bordered" width="100%">
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked without javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use 'lengthMenu' together with buttons(copy, export), you have to use this option dom: 'lBfrtip'.
Here https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom you can find meaning of each symbol.
For example, if you will use like this 'Bfrtip', lengthMenu will not appears.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@latest" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
<script src="js/datatables-simple-demo.js"></script>
<script src="js/tables.js"></script>
```

`download/copas` from online link if you have in footer tag. and copy paste make offline js extension like `tables.js`. then, you can edit the number of entries. You can search with keyword "entries per page" in `tables.js`. Find on near that keyword