# jquery datatable: page length select list not shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery Datatable:  1.10.7 and https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu

JS code:

```
      $('.table').dataTable({ 
'lengthMenu': [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, 'All'] ], 
'aoColumns': [null, null, null, { 'bSortable': false }, { 'bSortable': false }] }); // eslint-disable-line new-cap
```

Output:
[image]

But I need the following list to set page length:

[image]

How to do? Anything missing?

**UPDATE**

Output html:

```
<div id="DataTables_Table_0_length" class="dataTables_length">
   <label>
      Show 
      <select class="" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" name="DataTables_Table_0_length">
         <option value="10">10</option>
         <option value="25">25</option>
         <option value="50">50</option>
         <option value="-1">All</option>
      </select>
      entries
   </label>
</div>
```

But it is not shown at all.

**UPDATE**

The reason is:

```
.dataTables_length {
        display: none;
}
```

Comment: What version of dataTables are you using as they changed the parameter name a few times in the past.

Comment: "datatables": "git://github.com/DataTables/DataTables.git#1.10.7",

Comment: It looks that that parameter is now just `lengthChange` (no `b`)

Comment: "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 ]

Comment: @Antony Still missing "page length select list" https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu

Comment: @BAE please show us the `"dom" : ` options you are using, i think your problem with it.

Comment: @ShadyAlset Thanks. I already updated my post. I am not sure whether it is what you are looking for. I did not use ""dom": 'lrtip'" in my js codes. I just used default for almost everything

Comment: @BAE sorry but I meant the `dom: ` option of datatables such as `lengthMenu: ` or `aoColumns: ` and so on, have you used it in your table ?

Comment: @ShadyAlset already in my js codes. Thanks

Comment: @BAE oh the **l**ength changing input control is included in dom options, i thought it missed, Thanks.

Comment: Please see my update. Thanks

Comment: Please create a live example to work on it if you can, [live.datatables.net](http://live.datatables.net/)

Comment: You can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630853/change-values-of-select-box-of-show-10-entries-of-jquery-datatable/47885699#47885699

Answer (score 31):

Use the below dom value,

```
dom: 'Blfrtip',
```

Answer (score 9):

You might be using `Bfrtip` as **dom** value. Try using `Blfrtip`. It will show Export buttons as well length menu.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to report, You can try the following way to solve it.
Key point is to use dom:'Blfrtip'

```
 $('#tblClient').DataTable({
            dom: 'Blfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'colvis',
                'excel', {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    },
                    text: 'Download Pdf',
                    title: 'HCA Registration for Worker Portal',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    customize: function (doc) {
                        // Splice the image in after the header, but before the table
                        doc.content.splice(1, 0, {
                            margin: [0, 0, 0, 12],
                            alignment: 'center',
                            image: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA..'

                        });

                    }
                }],
            'ordering': true,
            'searching': true,
            'info': true,
            "serverSide": false,
            "lengthMenu": [[50, 100 - 1], [50, 100, "All"]],
            "pageLength": 50,
..
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify where in the dom the datatable widget will show the page size.

There is the dom option, something like this:

```
$('.table').dataTable({ 
'lengthMenu': [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, 'All']     ], 
'aoColumns': [null, null, null, { 'bSortable': false }, { 'bSortable': false }]
dom:'<"yourcssstyle"l>'
});
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Answer (score 0):

use id="datatable-keytable" in your table tag